# Angular Material $watch for Virtual Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Is it Possible to $watch for Virtual Repeat.

How to get current index on change

Answer (score 0):

In the ng-change, "this" is the current $scope, so you have access to both $index and whatever data element you did the md-virtual-repeat with.

For example:

```
<div md-virtual-repeat="row in rows">
  <input ng-change="valueChanged();">

$scope.valueChanged = function()
{
    var value = this.row.value;
    var index = this.$index;
}
```

And while that isn't precisely a $watch, it effectively does the same thing.  It informs you when the value changed.

Warning: Actually, it only informs you when the user did something.  If you change the value in your program, it will NOT be called.  You must call it yourself.